# slow multithreading with a simple procedure

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

I'm having a play with multi-threading (no prior experience) and have a simple function called from int main via two separate threads that just changes (and creates) a variable from within 2 for loops. As far as I can tell, there is no dependency between either thread but with one thread running my timing is 2.29 secs, and with two the timing is 7.11 secs (I would have expected something like 3-4 secs).

I am running on a netbook with two Intel atom CPUs (Ubuntu 10.04) - I am aware that neither thread will get the full "ownership" of a single CPU because the int main() process itself involves a thread (along with whatever the OS needs) but I'm shocked at the performance hit (presumably thread switching!?)

Is there any way I can make improvements here? (perhaps reduce the work the CPUs have to do to jump between threads). I am hoping to do something a little meatier soon (prime sieving with wheel factorization where different threads own different spokes)  but I'm not too impressed with the performance I'm getting right now

The simple code I have right now is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>"
#include <ctime>
#include <pthread.h>


void* foo(void* dummyVar)
{
    for(int i=1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j < 50000000; j++)
        {
            int test = j;
        }
            std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_attr_t attribute;
    void* status;
    pthread_attr_init(&attribute);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attribute, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    int i = 0;
    int b = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, foo, (void*)i);
    int c = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, foo, (void*)i);
    pthread_join(thread1, &status);
    pthread_join(thread2, &status);

    std::cout << ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Update: I get better performance (obviously!) by having the thread associated to main() call foo after just one other thread calls foo also (instead of two threads), albeit multithreading is still slower on this machine (having made some changes to foo - now just one for loop - the timings are 5.17 vs 6.01)

Comment: Too primitive/shortlived tasks might incur a higher thread switching overhead than their actual benefit.

Comment: In your case you are saying that the no of threads are more than hardware availability, that is point 1. Also your threads are doing negligible I/O so they remain busy most of the time and thus there is more contention among themselves and it gives bad performance.

Comment: I see...thanks for both comments here - would I be correct in saying then that the multi-threading I have planned for the future on this machine (wheel sieving with 8 spokes) has a good chance at being similarly doomed (given they would be fairly trivial for loops (with a small function to get the starting point) flipping 1's in prime indicator arrays)? - I haven't coded it up yet but I can't see there being much more than five instructions per loop (and jumping between spokes)

Comment: you could always design a parallel algorithm if there is scope and create a program for that. Even if it would not perform well on your machine but can do well on some other machines where more cores are available for the threads to execute. Performance is relative to machines.

Comment: Cheers for that...I'll give it a shot with a 4-core machine later (not with me yet though)...is there any way of predicting when the threads will switch (so to design my algorithms around that)? I've tried messing with my foo function but not getting any improvements here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    for(int j=1; j < 50000000; j++)
    {
        int test = j;
    }
```

Proper bench-marking can be a fine art, but this one falls flat quickly.  The only way for this code to survive is to forget to turn on the optimizer.  Which on any decent compiler will entirely eliminate the loop because it has no useful side-effects.

Assuming you actually did turn the optimizer, you are actually measuring 10 times

```
  std::cout << i << "\n";
```

A statement that can never run concurrently, the thread will be fighting over the lock that serializes access to the terminal/console.  With the expected outcome that this will indeed be slower.

But good odds that you forgot the optimizer, never profile code without it turned on, you won't ship it that way.

Comment: Aha! thank you very much for pointing that one out - the compiler certainly does kill off the loop if I set the optimize flag (yes I forgot it!) - further playing about and setting a static variable outside foo to the value of J+i (a side effect it didn't (at least in this case) optimize away) and commenting out the std::cout I now have that multithreading wins slightly with the following: 1.18 vs 1.21